# How to troubleshoot Amazon Connect CCP error "awsapps.com refused to connect"

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, connection-refused, amazon-connect

I have added the domain (`https://localhost:9111`) in `approved regions` of my `amazon connect instance` but i am still getting the Refused to Connect error, in inspection/console i have found `Refused to display '<URL>' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`
But when the agent/user logged in into the CCP this automatically went off and i can able to see the CCP stuff and make some calls and receive the calls. It's throwing the error and login page, its so weird as why then its working for other pages of CCP? Although it's work fine when we add `Ignore X-Frame Header Extension`.

How to get rid of this `Refused to connect error!` anyone who has done it before?

Refused To Connect - Error
[image: Refused To Connect - Error]

When logged in from a new window
[image: When logged in from a new window]

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://localhost:9111` instead of `https`. Make sure to update the origin in the Connect console as well.